# Is there an extension to limit activity types to contact types?

Tags: extension, activity

We have a custom activity type that should only be added to contacts of a specific contact subtype (ie activity targets must be of given contact subtype)

Is there an extension to enforce this?

Comment: +1, and also that the types of activity may be limited depending on the user role/permission, for example volunteers can't create/edit/view activities of type "Volunteer interview"

Comment: For role/permission there is https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl. Not sure if there's something for the original question.

Comment: We have something in beta now which does this, though it doesn't enforce heavily on the form validation side -- just makes the activities unavailable for New Activity creation under the contact's Activities tab. I'll get you a link momentarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in this:

[CiviCRM: Hide Activity Types (com.joinery.hideactivitytypes)](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.hideactivitytypes)

> Hide activity types in one or more ways:
>
> - Remove the activity type from the "Actions" list on the Activity Summary.
> - On a per-contact-type basis: activity type will be removed from the "New Activity" list under a contact's Activities tab, based on the contact's Type or Sub-Type.

[image]

Note, however, it only does what's stated above. It won't prevent creating activities in some other way, e.g., via api, or the New Activiy form. (But if  features for more aggressive limitation are desired, I think it would be a good fit to add them.)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of Aidan, but sounds like something that could be very useful!